# Views relationship based on user viewing node

Tags: users, views

So this is what im looking to do:

I have added a field to my users where they can enter their age in a numerical value.

I also have a referenced product which can only show on its referencing node.

I would like the view to only display the referenced product on its referencing node if the users age is greater than 18.

I have setup the content view and can get the referenced product to display on its referencing node however when I add the age field as a filter it can only reference the relationship I set as content:author as this was the closest I could find. What I want is something like user session etc so it references the current logged in user.

Any ideas would be great.

Thanks all